# Does the SVN plug-in work in MonoDevelop 2.4.2 on Windows 7?

Tags: mono, monodevelop

It says the plug-in is installed but it won't let me publish. Any type of magic I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monodevelop 2.6 beta 3 actually fixes the SVN plugin issues.